# MFC Treeview: Parent node not returning its child node

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am working on a project where i am facing difficulty with the MFC Tree control. I want to check whether any of its child node is selected. When the parent node is selected(Non expanded) and when i use GetChildItem() on the parent, it is returning null. If i repeat the same after expanding the parent node and again collapsing it is returning the child item.

```
if(this->ItemHasChildren(hItem))  //returning true (and i am sure that it has children)
{
    HTREEITEM hChild = this->GetChildItem (hItem);  //returning NULL;
}
```

If i expand and collapse the tree, the above code doesn't return NULL.

Comment: It seems you are not alone having this bug ... https://www.google.pt/search?client=opera&q=GetChildItem&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#channel=suggest&q=GetChildItem+ctreectrl

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
HTREEITEM hItem = treeCtrl->GetRootItem();
if (treeCtrl->ItemHasChildren(hItem))
{
    hItem = treeCtrl->GetNextItem(hItem, TVGN_CHILD);

    //do things

    while (hItem != NULL)
    {
        hItem = treeCtrl->GetNextItem(hItem, TVGN_NEXT);
        //do things
    }
}
```

And if you want to go deeper in the tree you will have to do a recursive function based on this.